# Why compiler doesn't generate a duplicate error?

Tags: java, class

Why the code below can be compiled successful?

- The second statement `int a = 2` defined just within the scope of `int a = 2`, why it can be compiled successfully?

  ```
  class Test {
      int a = 1;         // variable a,
      { 
          int a = 2;     //duplicate variable
      }
  }

  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(new Test().a);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int a = 2;` is a local variable of an instance initializer block. As such, it is added to the body of each constructor of your `Test` class as a local variable. Local variables are allowed to have the same name as instance variables (this allows you, for example, to have a constructor whose argument names are identical to the names of the corresponding instance variables). They simply hide the instance variables of the same name (forcing you to qualify the name with `this.` if you want to refer to the instance variable).

```
class Test {
    int a = 1;        
    { 
        int a = 2; 
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
class Test {
    int a = 1;
    public Test ()
    { 
        int a = 2;
    }
}
```

While this snippet makes no sense (since we never use the value of the local variable `a`), having 2 variables named `a` (one a local variable and the other an instance variable) can make sense in the following example:

```
class Test {
    int a = 1;
    public Test (int a)
    { 
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```